# Using ASP.Net Core automapper and trying to check if the value is null so I can set the value conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Using automapper to fetch first image that is the 'IsMain' and will set PhotoUrl to null if no image exists. But now I want to check if the image is null and add another condition to set the url to something else, such as

```
if (src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain) == null) {
   if (user.gender == 'male') {
     // set PhotoUrl to something here
   }
}
```

here is my automapper create map call

```
CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt => {
      opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url);
   })
});
```

I tried adding an extension like this, but it doesn't even get called if the value is null.

```
opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url.GetDefaultMemberImage(src.Gender));

public static string GetDefaultMemberImage(this string photoUrl, string gender) {
        if (photoUrl == null) {
            if (gender == "male") {
                return "url1";
            } else {
                return "url2";
            }
        } else {
            return photoUrl;
        }
    }
```

I was thinking I could change "src.Photos.FirstOrDefault()" to something else, but not sure what?

Comment: You need AM 8.1.1.

Comment: why do I need 8.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `opt.MapFrom`, you could use expression to check whether the `src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain)` is null.

Try something like

```
CreateMap<UserPhoto, UserPhotoDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
    src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain) == null ? (src.Gender == "male" ? "url1" : "url2") : src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url));
```

Comment: thanks! still learning the syntax for this, so this really helped!